# Separate an Access db into distinct data and interface files?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I've seen it done once, but didn't understand why the builder did this.  What's the advantage, and if there is one, why is there no example of such an architecture in the literature?

I'm just looking for a best-practice approach for a small office of around <10 or so users before I begin it (an office that wants specifically to migrate to an Access db).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tons of [links](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/split-an-access-database-HA010342026.aspx) on how and why to split your app and database into separate files. In your application each user has a local copy of the app file which is linked to the data file in some sort of shared folder.

Performance is improved. Network traffic is limited. Unique copies of temp/cached data can be maintained if needed. Backups on the data are slightly smaller. Not all users require the same features, so you can have different apps using the same data. A manager that just needs a few reports doesn't need a file with 50 forms in it.

**I'd like to know what you see as the downside.** Linking tables isn't that hard (If it is, get someone else to build this app.). Sending everyone an updated app file to save on their local machine isn't that hard especially in a LAN setting.

Comment: Don't forget http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa167840(v=office.11).aspx. There is an auto updater available from Tony Toews to make front-end updates easy. Re-linking can be easily automated.

Comment: Remou, really useful link.  Thanks!  Jeff, I don't see a downside, but had never see it done with Access as the back end.  I'll know more in a few days about whether they're intent on really wanting a 100% Access solution.  Good comments, all.

Comment: No downside? How about an immediate drop in performance after the split that apparently comes from the constant creation/deletion of the "lock" file on the data part of it?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you mean two distinct Access files, one with only the system interface, and the other with the database, right?

If that's the case the answer is pretty simple.

Doing like so will provide means to update the interface without any downtime of the system operation and can help on the backup of the data.

Access files can store both the data and the user interface, if you're using the Access like this, so, any modification in the file affects every one that uses the system.

However, for the scenario that you're painting, I'd upgrade that to a SQL Server Express and an actual software developed for the company.

Comment: I don't start the job for the next day or so, and haven't yet had an opportunity to speak with the place about whether they'll be amenable to SQL Server Express, but that's a very good suggestion.  Do you think Access would still be a good choice for the front end?

Comment: Just remember that SQL Server Express is **FREE**. Some people tend to hear of SQL Server and think $$$$

Comment: This seems like overkill for less than 10 users.

Comment: Don't forget that maintenance on SQL Srver Express is more complicated than Access.

Comment: @Remou not quite so, the maintenance of a SQL Server Express is pretty simple, and you can configure automatic backups and what not. Starting with more than 5 simultaneous users the SQL Server Express is a better solution. The probability of a corrupted Access file, even a modern one, is pretty high.

Comment: Free is certainly something I'll mention to them when I meet with them in a few days, and more involved maintenance is a consideration I imagine the clients might have been worried about when they just wanted an Access answer.

Comment: In many years, I have only once had a corrupted Access file, and the data was recoverable. You say the maintenance is simple, but not as simple as weekly compact and repair and a file copy for back-up and restore. You can train any user to run maintenance on Access.

Comment: I'd much prefer to use SQL Server Express or MySQL for the store, but Remou makes some interesting points.

Comment: If security is a consideration , it is a good idea, but if your clients want control, it is probably not.

Comment: I'll know more in a few days.  Will certainly be back for more advice.  Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @PauloSantos: SQL Server Express does NOT include the Backup Agent, so you have to write and schedule your own backup script. That's just one of many things that makes its administration more complicated than a Jet/ACE back end.